# Use Gremlin to find the shortest path in a graph avoiding a given list of vertices?

Tags: graph, neo4j, traversal, gremlin

I need to use Gremlin find the shortest path between two nodes (vertices) while avoiding a list of given vertices.

I already have:

`v.bothE.bothV.loop(2){!it.object.equals(y)}.paths>>1`

To get my shortest path.

I was attempting something like:

`v.bothE.bothV.filter{it.name!="ignored"}.loop(3){!it.object.equals(y)}.paths>>1`

but it does not seem to work.

Please HELP!!!

Comment: You could use the neo4j graph algorithms: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/graph-algo.html. Of course you would need to do it outside gremlin. I personally combine gremlin with calling neo4j directly if I use neo4j in the embedded mode.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The second solution you have looks correct. However, to be clear on what you are trying to accomplish. If x and y are the vertices that you want to find the shortest path between and a vertex to ignore during the traversal if it has the property name:"ignored", then the query is:

```
x.both.filter{it.name!="ignored"}.loop(2){!it.object.equals(y)}.paths>>1
```

If the "list of given vertices" you want filtered is actually a list, then the traversal is described as such:

```
list = [ ... ] // construct some list
x.both.except(list).loop(2){!it.object.equals(y)}.paths>>1
```

Moreover, I tend to use a range filter just to be safe as this will go into an infinite loop if you forget the >>1 :)

```
x.both.except(list).loop(2){!it.object.equals(y)}[1].paths>>1
```

Also, if there is a potential for no path, then to avoid an infinitely long search, you can do a loop limit (e.g. no more than 4 steps):

```
x.both.except(list).loop(2){!it.object.equals(y) & it.loop < 5}.filter{it.object.equals(y)}.paths>>1
```

Note why the last filter step before paths is needed. There are two reasons the loop is broken out of. Thus, you might not be at y when you break out of the loop (instead, you broke out of the loop because it.loops < 5).

Here is you solution implemented over the Grateful Dead graph distributed with Gremlin. First some set up code, where we load the graph and define two vertices x and y:

```
gremlin> g = new TinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> g.loadGraphML('data/graph-example-2.xml')
==>null
gremlin> x = g.v(89) 
==>v[89]
gremlin> y = g.v(100) 
==>v[100]
gremlin> x.name
==>DARK STAR
gremlin> y.name
==>BROWN EYED WOMEN
```

Now your traversal. Note that there is not name:"ignored" property, so instead, I altered it to account for the number of performances of each song along the path. Thus, shortest path of songs played more than 10 times in concert:

```
gremlin> x.both.filter{it.performances > 10}.loop(2){!it.object.equals(y)}.paths>>1
==>v[89]
==>v[26]
==>v[100]
```

If you use Gremlin 1.2+, then you can use a path closure to provide the names of those vertices (for example) instead of just the raw vertex objects:

```
gremlin> x.both.filter{it.performances > 10}.loop(2){!it.object.equals(y)}.paths{it.name}>>1
==>DARK STAR
==>PROMISED LAND
==>BROWN EYED WOMEN
```

I hope that helps.

Good luck!
Marko.

Comment: Great answer thanks Marko. Very through! Just one question that I'm sure you can answer for me. I couldn't get it working with the query stated in my question, but when I changed it to: v.bothE.bothV.filter{it.getProperty('name')!='ignored'}.loop(3){!it.object.equals(y)}.paths>>1 it worked, ie using it.getProperty. Why is that?

Comment: This works as intended because the pipes within a loop are evaluated breadth-first (see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gremlin-users/X8sOoijCPhY/67-hlKiKy5EJ). If this were not the case, then if there was a 3-step path from x to y through vertex a but there was a 2-step path through vertex b, and the very first vertex returned from the both pipe was vertex a then this pipeline would return the 3-step path, not the shortest one.